# Interface Builder: How to clean up the deleted constraint?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I used command-delete to remove some constraints on the Map View widget in IB. Instead of being completely removed, the constraints are actually just faded as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

I have tried both saving the file and reopening the project, but it seems like they will not be removed by XCode.

How can I get them removed?

**EDIT**

This is what I see in the Size Inspector window

[image]

I am using XCode 6 (6A313)

Comment: This is to do with size classes. If you add a constraint in AnyAny and then delete it in another size class, say AnyCompact then it will look like this. This is because you have openly deleted it from that size class. Not from all of them.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for your comment. However I don't think I have changed the size classes explicitly throughout the process. I will google more about this

Comment: I'm certain that's what it is. That's the only reason that constraints look like that.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have no doubt you're correct. I just know too little about autolayout. I did not recall changing the size classes, but I could have changed it without knowing it. Thanks again and I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you select the constraint and look in the inspector panel on the left it should tell you which size classes that constraint is valid for. You can also delete it from there too but you have to select the constraint. Not just the view it relates to.

Comment: I hope someone can tell us how to automatically delete all of these faded constraints in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using cmd and delete, select the view ,goto size inspector and delete the constraints there,
 here is the screen shot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However in my XCode I did not find the 'delete' option as in your screenshot. I have updated the question and attached what I see in Size Inspector.

Answer (score 10):

Select it in the left panel and hit backspace to delete for good.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me too. And it turned out the grayed constraints were (somehow, inexplicably) causing an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error. So one of my necessary constraints was being dropped at runtime in order to keep one of the deleted (and unwanted!) constraints around.

Comment: Thanks for this, was using cmd+backspace instead. What does cmd+backspace do? Shortcut to uninstall for current size class?

Comment: Just DELETE key now just "uninstall" the constraint from the current size classes configuration, but it still may be used in other configurations. So why it's still may causes constraints conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove particular object related all constraint then go to 'Resolve Autolayout Issue button' which appear little menu bar at the bottom of the editor  select 'Clear Constraint'.

if you want to remove particular constraint of any object then select object -> go to size inpecter -> click on the first right button appear on constraing-> delete .

If you want to remove all constraint related to particular xib then go to 'Resolve Autolayout Issue button' and select 'Clear All Constraint in  View'

Answer (score 1):

The constraints are faded because you removed them from the size inspector of one view but not from the other involved view.

If you add a constraint between 2 views you will see that constraint in the size inspector of both views. If you remove the constraint from the size inspector of one view, you will still see it in the size inspector of the other view, and you will also see the constraint faded in the view controller scene tree.

You can remove the constraint completely (from both views) by deleting it from the view controller scene tree (or from the very scene).