# XCode: How to find all then delete all disable constraints

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in iOS. I see a lot of disable constraints in my `Main.storyboard` and I want to delete it.
However, my `Main.storyboard` have many screen so I want to find the way to find all disable constraints then delete all.
Is it possible with `Xcode`?
**Or** any way to prevent disable constraint generate.
Any help would be great appreciate

[image]

Comment: for >prevent disable constraint generate,  the constraint which are already disabled are not going to affect your vide or design

Comment: Please See This Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946812/interface-builder-how-to-clean-up-the-deleted-constraint

Comment: @Rajesh but I want to find all then delete all, not find then delegate each constraint

Answer (score 7):

Obviously there's the manual way, of going through all of the constraints in Interface Builder and just deleting the disabled ones.

But, if you have a tonne of disabled ones and you just want to wipe them all out, you can edit the storyboard file directly (do this with Xcode closed).

You could build a script to this, but here's the manual process to start with.

Look in the Storyboard file for lines such as: `<exclude reference="egm-9S-fZb"/>`
In this case, `egm-9S-fZb` is the id of the constraint that's disabled.
Now find a line in the storyboard like this: `<constraint ... id="egm-9S-fZb"/>`

Delete both of those lines and you've deleted that disabled constraint.

Note: Be aware that if you have constraints that are disabled in certain conditions, i.e., you have a constraint that's only enabled for say Compact Width, Compact Height, it will be listed with an `exclude` line, as well as an `include` line. So check for an `include` line before deleting the `exclude` and the `constraint` lines.

Comment: thank you for your answer. you are right in find the disable constraint in Xcode source code. However, each constraint have different id, so find each constraint id then delete still cause many time like the using the interface
But now i'm using your solution for finding where is the disable constraint (i mean which viewcontroller). then I open the interface builder and delete it

Answer (score 0):

Disable constraints are generated when you create a constraint and delete it from under "Size inspector (one with ruler like)". Just remember to delete it from your scene, then you will not have disable constraint floating around...or just delete it when u see it :).

Answer (score -1):

@Dace Wood and @Bao Tran already said some useful measures. I would like to add something.

If these disabled constraints are only for a specific view object, you can manually delete those disabled constraints from IB and then add new ones. Or to take risk, you can use the **"Reset to suggested Constraints"** or **"Add Missing Constraints"** seen in **"Resolve Auto Layout issues"** seen in bottom right part of storyboard. It is really helpful.